# Clang++ - How to dump AST of CUDA code?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++, llvm-clang

It's said that clang support CUDA recently. But I can't find the usage in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find what usage in what document? Is this what you are looking for? http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html